# Delphi - Can you close all of the database tables?

Tags: delphi

Can you close all database tables except some? Can you then reopen them? I use an absolute database that is similar to BDE. If this is possible, how can I do so many?

Comment: Yes, of course you can.  You could iterate the `Components` property of your form/datamodule, use the `is` operator to check whether each is an instance of your table type and use a cast to call `Open` or `Close` on it.

Comment: Hello . Thank you
I have 140 tables.
I have to find a procedure that closes all of them, except for some that I need.

Comment: See the example in my answer.  It's up to you how you decide which tables to leave open, I can't do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can. You could iterate the Components property of your form/datamodule, use the is operator to check whether each is an instance of your table type and use a cast to call Open or Close on it.

The following closes all TABSDataSet tables on your form except one called Table1.

```
procedure TForm1.ProcessTables;
var
  ATable : TABSDataSet;  // used to access a particular TABSDataSet found on the form
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do begin
    if Components[i] is TABSDataSet then begin
      ATable := TABSDataSet(Components[i]);
      //  Now that you have a reference to a dataset in ATable, you can
      //  do whatever you like with it.  For example
      if ATable.Active and (ATable <> Table1) then
        ATable.Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I've seen from the code you've posted in comments and your answer that you
are obviously having trouble applying my code example to your situation.  You
may find the following code easier to use:

```
procedure ProcessTables(AContainer : TComponent);
var
  ATable : TABSTable;
  i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to AContainer.ComponentCount - 1 do begin
    if AContainer.Components[i] is TABSTable then begin
      ATable := TABSTable(AContainer.Components[i]);
      //  Now that you have a reference to a dataset in ACDS, you can
      //  do whatever you like with it.  For example
      if ATable.Active then
        ATable.Close;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Note that this is a stand-alone procedure, not a procedure of a particular
form or datamodule.  Instead, when you use this procedure, you call it passing
whatever form or datamodule contains the TABSTables you want to work with as the
`AContainer` parameter,  like so

```
if Assigned(DataModule1) then
  ProcessTables(DataModule1);
```

or

```
if Assigned(Form1) then
  ProcessTables(Form1);
```

However, the downside of doing it this was is that it is trickier to specify which tables, if any, to leave open, because AContainer, being a TComponent, will not have any member tables.

Btw, your task would probably be easier if you could iterate through the tables in a TABSDatabase.  However I've looked at its online documentation but can't see an obvious way to do this;  I've asked the publishers, ComponentAce, about this but haven't had a reply yet.

Comment: So it closes everything?
If I want table 1/2/3/4/5 that opens?

Comment: Then you have to add logic to if ACDS.Active` to do what you want. F.i. `if ACDS.Active and (ACDS <> Table1) and (ACDS <> Table2) [etc] then ...`

Comment: Well, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: with Tabsdataset does not close anything

Comment: if ACDS.active then ...... if use  ACDS : TABSdatabase ....[dcc32 Error] E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'active'

Comment: I'm not sure where the assumption you use Advantage comes from. I suppose you use this: http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/overview.htm ?

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful:  I misread the OP's reference to "an abolute database", thanks for spotting.

Comment: In case I got the [documentation for "Absolute DB"](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/absdbmanual_content.htm) right, then the base class you're going for should be `TABSDataSet`, not `TABSDatabase`. A Dataset is something like a table, query and whatnot.

Comment: "ACDS : TABSdataset; or ACDS : TABSdatabase; ??? "  It really doesn't sound like you are putting any effort into trying to understand what to do.  Firstly, replace `ACDS` by something like `ATable` (see update to answer) , then replace `TClientDataSet` with the type of table/dataset component you are **actually** using.

Comment: thanks to martina you are too kind.
If you look I modified the error code is: list index out of bound

Comment: I have rejected your edit.  You have got into a muddle between the dataset collection you were trying to add and the Components collection of the form.  What you should do is test that my code does what it is supposed to do (it will) and them write a separate procedure that uses your dataset collection - do NOT mix them up like you did with your attempted edit.

Comment: It does not close any tables.
Where do I put this procedure in the datamodule?

Comment: Btw, you said "with Tabsdataset does not close anything"  NEVER use `with`!!!  It causes far more problems than it ever solves.

Comment: "It does not close any tables."  Then post a new question showing the code you are trying to use; t needs to be an MCVE (see SO online help)

Comment: hello many thanks 
exception argument out of range !!!!
I get this error